# Paths and calculation of action in the phase space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral, many-body, propagator

In the Hamilton-Jacobi formulation, what can we say about those paths which are restricted to say an energy $E$ subspace? If so, then when evaluating the propagator in a many-body problem, can we then connect the probability of being found in a state to the number of such paths in the phase space? As it should be, statistically speaking.

Are people aware of something like this?